# Oracle Opera PMS Kiosk Checkout Failed - do_authorization failed

Tags: oracle

I am trying to set up Kiosk interface checkout option for our hotel guest, when I tried to checkout the reservation from Kiosk, it failed. Below is the message from Opera OWS log:

`kiosk_ifc_res->Checkout->checkout: ifc8_remote_co.do_authorization failed<- Locator -> Checkout : ifc8_remote_co.do_authorization:`

Understand that this is payment related issue where Opera is trying to settle the payment upon checkout, and because we haven't have a payment solution setup yet, thus this error.

Hence, **how can I configure Opera in a way that my Kiosk can checkout without settling the payment?** I am fine that the reservation has open charges during checkout (we have another team to handle the charges).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by setting the payment method to be Manual.

Can be set by going to Setup > Cashiering > Codes > Transaction Codes > Select the payment method to configure, under Credit Card, click the "Manual" radio button.